# jPlayer not playing mp3 in Firefox

Tags: jquery, jplayer

I'm integrating jplayer to play a selection of mp3 files triggered by an click event using jQuery. The code used to achieve this is:

```
$('.play-link').click(function() {
    $("#jquery_jplayer_1").jPlayer("destroy");
        srcFile = $(this).attr('href');
        $("#jquery_jplayer_1").jPlayer({
        ready: function (event) {
            $(this).jPlayer("setMedia", {
            mp3:srcFile
            }).jPlayer("play");
        },
        swfPath: "http://www.mydomain.co.uk/swf/Jplayer.swf",
        supplied: "mp3",
        wmode: "window"
    });
return false;
});
```

`srcFile` is set from the href of the link clicked.

This all works fine in the various versions of IE and Chrome but not in Firefox.  Using Firebug the swf is being loaded into the browser so the swfPath appears to be correct but nothing further happens when the player is initialised.

Is anybody able to shed any light on why this would not be working in Firefox alone?

Thanks

Comment: You reference `$(this)` when defining your srcFile - give us the rest of the object / function definition.

Comment: @Crontab - I've added the full object as used.  Thanks.

Comment: Are you testing with the latest version of Flash and Firefox?

Comment: Try using a relative path to the `swf` instead of an absolute one.

Comment: @Skoder it's the latest version of flash player and Firefox 8.

Comment: @keyboardP switched to a relative path and no difference is made.

Comment: Just in case... The flash player must be visible, i.e. no display:none on your player div!

Comment: is there any particular reason you destroy the jPlayer instance on every click? I've never known this to be necessary..

Comment: I paid no attention to the click definition, sorry.  I wonder if FF is doing something screwy with URL.  Could you throw `alert(srcFile);` in there and see if it's consistent across browsers?

Answer (score 2):

MP3 files are not supported by Firefox and therefore jPlayer will not play them while running in the FF browser.

You must have .ogg audio files for jPlayer to work in Firefox. See below list of browsers and their respective compatible files:

```
HTML5 browsers and their supported audio file formats:

Firefox (OSX, Win): WEBMA, OGA
Safari (OSX, Win): MP3, M4A
Mobile Safari iOS4 (iPad, iPhone, iPod): MP3, M4A
Opera (OSX, Win): WEBMA, OGA
Chrome (OSX, Win): WEBMA, OGA, MP3, M4A
IE9 (Win): MP3, M4A (Can install the WebM codec.)
```

Answer (score 0):

Set 'solution' attribute. Make it compatible with IE9 as well.

```
var player = $("#jquery_jplayer_1").jPlayer({        
    ready: function (event) {
        $(this).jPlayer("setMedia", {
            mp3:srcFile
        }).jPlayer("play");
    },
    swfPath: "http://www.mydomain.co.uk/swf/Jplayer.swf",
    supplied: "mp3",
    wmode: "window",
    solution: navigator.userAgent.indexOf("Trident/5")>-1 ? "flash" : "html,flash"
});
```